# Refreshing Azure App Configuration Based on Label

Tags: azure, azure-app-configuration

I have created an Azure App Configuration and added several Feature Gates to it
Following the documentation I added a different label to each one to represent a different environment.

The following snippet in Program.cs works when I do not define labels and the features

```
 config.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
                        {
                            options.Connect(connectionString)
                            .Select(KeyFilter.Any)
                                   .ConfigureRefresh(refresh =>
                                        refresh.Register(KeyFilter.Any, true)
                                          .SetCacheExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)));

                            options.UseFeatureFlags();

                        });
                    });
```

By works i mean
The features load and changing the feature in the Azur App Config causes the changes to hot change within 10 - 15 seconds.

For each Feature I have the following labels "Development", "Staging", "Production"

I can make the correct keys load on start up by using the following code

```
 config.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
                        {
                            options.Connect(connectionString)
                            .Select(KeyFilter.Any, "Staging") // For example 
                                   .ConfigureRefresh(refresh =>
                                        refresh.Register(KeyFilter.Any, true)
                                          .SetCacheExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)));

                            options.UseFeatureFlags();

                        });
                    });
```

This will load the correct keys, but updating the values in the Azure portal doesnt refresh.

Tried several different techniques, but the refresh never updates if i have specified a label.

Is this a limitation or is my terminology wrong.

I have also tried several other things such as

```
refresh.Register(KeyFilter.Any,"Staging", true)
```

```
refresh.Register("SpecificKey","Staging", true)
```

But the refresh doesnt seem to work.

Any help would be great

Thank you

Added a bit more investigation

Here is an example of my app store, I am only using FeatureGates
[image: My App Store]

When I have any label on the refresh stops working although the initial load works.

Here is my current config code

```
                 config.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
                        {
                            options.Connect(connectionString);
                            options.Select(KeyFilter.Any, "Staging");
                            options.UseFeatureFlags(featureFlagOptions =>
                            {
                                featureFlagOptions.CacheExpirationInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
                            });

                        });
```

If I remove the label "Staging" from the feature gates and the code then every 30 seconds my app refreshes.

I have also demonstrated this behaviour on a console app which i will upload

Has anyone found a way to get featuremanagement flags to auto refresh if you have a label on them ?

Answer (score -1):

Did you miss below in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-feature-flag-aspnet-core?tabs=core6x#use-a-feature-flag)?

*When no parameter is passed to the UseFeatureFlags method, it loads all feature flags with no label in your App Configuration store. The default refresh expiration of feature flags is 30 seconds. You can customize this behavior via the FeatureFlagOptions parameter. For example, the following code snippet loads only feature flags that start with TestApp: in their key name and have the label dev. The code also changes the refresh expiration time to 5 minutes. Note that this refresh expiration time is separate from that for regular key-values.*

```cs
options.UseFeatureFlags(featureFlagOptions =>
{
    featureFlagOptions.Select("TestApp:*", "dev");
    featureFlagOptions.CacheExpirationInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
});
```

Comment: Hi, The initial selection works but the refresh doesnt,
I am also using featuremanagement demonstrated in my screenshot above; i have to say i find the mixed documentation very confusing

Comment: Hi, Ive tried every combination,
The initial selection works but they never  reload unless I restart the app. 

I have tried console apps, push model, pull model, as soon as they have a label they do not refresh.

None of the samples demonstrate this,  

Its a bit annoying as I went as far as setting up service buses, event grids but the settings do not work and the refresher does not pick up label changes 

If you have a sample app that demonstrates this, that would be fantastic but labels prevent auto updating

Comment: Ive upload a sample app here which demonstrates it 
https://github.com/whatisthejava/app-config-demo-labels/blob/main/Program.cs


In the Program populate the app store endpoint and create a feature flag called TEST 
Execute the console app and the refresher picks up the change 
Add a label to TEST 
and the console app doesnt 

To test the change 
I Deleted the feature flag named TEST with no label and replaced with TEST and a label of Staging
I changed the line
              .Select(KeyFilter.Any);
to
              .Select(KeyFilter.Any, "Staging");
And the app stops updating

Comment: Hey, why dont you explain one more time instead of reading all the different things I have tried, all the different configs and run the console app that I uploaded which demonstrates that the refresh doesnt work.

But sure , keep telling me the same answer and i will keep telling you that your solution is wrong